# Browser link to Windows share in Ubuntu and OS X

Tags: linux, macos, network-shares, samba

In Windows, I am able to create a bookmark in any browser to a file on a network share, like so:

```
file://network/path/to/file/example.htm
```

This works well in Windows because it avoids needing a complicated content server to serve up basic pages. The bigger reason is that it's a corporate network and we can't have a web server.

Is there a way this can be done similarly in Linux and OS X? Samba is installed, but how could the URL be formatted to point to the file on the Windows share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows shares use the [SMB protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) for file sharing.

To use such shares in Linux, you must have installed the package sambe-client. To expose such shares from your computer, you need sambe-server.

The syntax for a shared file is `smb://computer/sharename/...`.

Not all browsers allow the SMB protocol in their initial configuration.

For example, the last answer in the thread [Firefox smb woes](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/firefox-smb-woes-any-ideas-781219/) says :

> this solution is specific to firefox 3.5 and higher under GNOME.
>
> Step 1: Firefox about:config
>
> ```
> network.protocol-handler.expose.smb : false
> network.protocol-handler.external.smb : true
> ```
>
> Step 2: At the command line:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/smb/command '/usr/bin/nautilus %s' --type String
> gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/smb/enabled --type Boolean true
> ```
>
> Step 3: Run firefox and enter your smb URL into the address bar, eg:
>
> ```
> smb://myserver/myfolder
> ```
>
> a menu will pop up asking you which application to use. select
>   nautilus, click the "always use" checkbox.

Comment: For OS X, you should be able to ommit step 2 as smb:// is already bound to Finder.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, a connected SMB share will be mounted as `/Volumes/<share name>` (with spaces in the share name being replaced by %20 – see [this Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568) on SMB share connection). The URL to your file would thus be:

```
file:///Volumes/share/path/to/file.html
```

As to Ubuntu, I am no expert, but [this Ubuntu Documentation article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) indicates how to permanently connect to a SMB share, and once you have done that, the file URL should be constructed in a way analogous to the OS X one, starting with the mount point chosen in `fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

try `CrankWheel Screen Sharing`
in chrome install the extension and share your chrome tab, or full screen.

the client without install anything ,just need a browser to open the share url

Answer (score -2):

On OS X, smb://myserver/myfolder works out-of-the-box in Safari browser.